# Does .Net have any built-in controls to ensure message integrity?

Tags: .net, integrity

I know I could go and read the source code of the Framework, but in the interests of saving time and getting something back fro mthe community, does anyone know if any .Net classes specifically ensure messages are delivered correctly, or if the protocols themselves handle this.

For example, I want to make sure of the following scenarios:

- My SQL statement is received at the server as I wrote it, and the results that arrive back are exactly as the server sent them
- My web service calls send and receive exactly what is expected
- My .Net remoting calls send and receive exactly what is expected
- Same for WCF

This is to check that the packets haven't been tampered with, that a network outage doesn't mean some data has been lost etc.

This specifically relates to ISO 27001, A12.2.3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) does this.

Comment: @Danny - put this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF TCP Binding has a notion of reliable messaging, which will ensure your data contracts are reliably delivered. There's also encryption/signing feature you can read more about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733137.aspx).